# User DB, authetication and migrations

Tags: database, back, migrate

We are currently considering using Janrain on our website instead of developing the social login apps ourselves. The questions we have are:

1) When we get access to a user's set of data, do we get to store that data in our db?

2) Will the data be stored in a way/format that if I ever want to switch providers or migrate back to my own app (facebook connect or login with twitter) it will work without the need for users to register again?

3) I assume the authentication process has to be repeated if I switch providers. If that happens, will the IDs captured from the social network and the one normalized by Janrain match in a way that I know it is the same user if I ever migrate out of Janrain?

Basically, I want to make sure that if I ever grow my user base, but do not generate enough revenues to pay for Janrain, that I will be able to migrate out of Janrain without much pain to me or my users.

Thanks in advance for the help

Leo

Answer (score 1):

To answer question one the answer is yes janrain provides a redirect script that you can modify and do with it what you please.
For number two that is entirely up to you, your login script for this purpose should register user if not already registered and then login.
For number three yes.